# JavaScript, array.sort() two arrays based on only one of them

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I just discovered `array.sort()` and saw that I can specify how to sort like this: (example taken from http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp)

```
var points = [40,100,1,5,25,10];
points.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});
```

I've been doing my sorting manually just using Bubble Sort because the arrays are small, but I was wondering if `array.sort()` can be used in place of this:

```
// Sort rowCategories[i] by rowWidth[i]
swapped = true;
while (swapped) {
    swapped = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < rowCategories.length-1; i++) {
        if (rowWidth[i] < rowWidth[i+1]) {
            var swap = rowCategories[i];
            rowCategories[i] = rowCategories[i+1];
            rowCategories[i+1] = swap;
            swap = rowWidth[i];
            rowWidth[i] = rowWidth[i+1];
            rowWidth[i+1] = swap;
            swapped = true;
        }
    }
}
```

What would I write for the built in sort to do the equivalent work?

Comment: You may sort an array of objects instead... (and w3school isn't very good. For reference you may want to see [`Array.sort` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) instead)

Comment: I agree, if you store both values in one object then you can simply use `sort`.

Comment: `rowCategories[]` is an array of objects (I think of it as a class), so I should make `rowWidth[]` part of it?

Comment: Yes, just add a `width:` property to each element.

Comment: Yes, I would use that approach if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this only requires a little modification. Instead of storing two arrays store one array with an object with the two attributes. Then you can do something like this.

`arr.sort(functiona(a,b){return a.rowWidth - b.rowWidth});`

the object must contain the attributes rowWidth and rowCatagories

Answer (score 2):

There is a way of multi sorting arrays but I like the array of objects better. Here is the multi sort:

```
function multisort(sortBy,otherArrays){
  var keys=[],i,tmpKeys;
  sortBy.sort(function(a,b){
    var ret=(a>b)?1:(a<b)?-1:0;
    // storing the return values to be used for the other arrays
    keys.push(ret);
    return ret;
  });
  for(i=0;i<otherArrays.length;i++){
    // copy the stored retun values
    tmpKeys=keys.concat([]);
    otherArrays[i].sort(function(){
      // return the saved values based on sortBy array's sort
      return tmpKeys.splice(0,1);
    });
  }
}

var arr1=[1,2,3],
arr2=[5,6,7],
reverse=["c","b","a"];
multisort(reverse,[arr1,arr2])
console.log(arr1);
console.log(arr2);
console.log(reverse);
```

Sorting by object key:

```
var arr=[
  {id:1,col1:3,col2:2},
  {id:2,col1:2,col2:2},
  {id:3,col1:1,col2:1}
];

function sortBy(arr,keys){
  var i=0;
  arr.sort(function(a,b){
    var i=0;
    while(a[keys[i]]===b[keys[i]]&&i<keys.length){
      i++;
    }
    return (keys.length===i)?0:(a[keys[i]]>b[keys[i]])?1:-1;
  });
}
//sort by col2 then col1
sortBy(arr,["col2","col1"]);
console.log(arr);
//sort by id
sortBy(arr,["id"]);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: I appreciate that you made that to answer the question (+1!), but I think that the suggestions of adding `rowWidth[]` to `rowCategories[]` is a simpler solution, thank you

Comment: @asimes I've added sorting by object key, if you have any questions please let me know.

Comment: The multi sort is some code I've seen on SO a while ago. It isn't mine but could not find the original post.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in `sort()` can only sort one array at a time, and the comparison is based on the values, not the indexes.

What you're doing is similar to PHP's `array_multisort()` function. If you use load the [php.js](http://phpjs.org/) library, it includes an implementation of this function. The implementation is [here](http://phpjs.org/functions/array_multisort/).

Comment: I guess it has to do with the fact that is a port, but jesus that function is some horrible horrible js code.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the vanilla the sort function uses depends on browser JS engine implementation, for instance Mozilla uses MergeSort I believe.

By default it compare array items as strings and if you need any other consideration you must pass your own compare function to sort and function must return negative, 0 or positive number indicating the items comparison result.

You can use this sort function instead of yours, that would be much faster.

Comment: How would you use it for the two-array sort that he's implementing?

Comment: What he can do is creating array consisting of pairs of `rowCategories` and `rowWidth` and then in function change the values respectively.

Comment: I'm guessing they all use Mergesort or Quicksort?